# I'm trying to build unique inputs on the fly with jQuery but am running into a iteration issue

Tags: jquery

I am creating a dynamic form with jQuery and I am able to make give the first two inputs a unique data-id, but the 3rd reverts to data-id 2, when I am hoping it would simply keep counting up. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addSpec', function(e) {

  //if a dynamic input does not exist
  if ($("#spec").data("id") != "1") {

    var id = 1;
    $("#customFields").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec" name="name1" data-id="' + id + '" placeholder="Spec Name" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec1" name="spec1" placeholder="" style="margin-bottom: 20px">');
  } else {
    //get the last created data-is and add 1
    var id = $("#spec").last().data("id") + 1;
    console.log(id);
    $("#customFields").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec" name="name' + id + '" data-id="' + id + '" placeholder="Spec Name" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec1" name="spec1" placeholder="" style="margin-bottom: 20px">');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=customFields>

</div>

<button class="w-50 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="addSpec">Add Spec</button>
```

Comment: could you show your html.?

Comment: Sure, one second

Comment: Added the html to the question

Comment: It’s not a good idea to add multiple elements with the same I’d into the dome. In this case you can run always into undefined behavior. Move the „spec“ in the I’d to the class and search for a class instead of an Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `id` multiple times which is bad practice! That's why I've just removed the `id` in this example. Then basically you generate always the same HTML with given "id" .. Why not like so?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addSpec', function(e) {

  //if a dynamic input does not exist
  var id = $('#customFields input[name^="spec"]').length +1;
  
    $("#customFields").append('<div><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name1" data-id="' + id + '" placeholder="Spec Name" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="spec1" placeholder="" style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=customFields>

</div>

<button class="w-50 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="addSpec">Add Spec</button>
```

**Note:** There is no reason to add a number to the `name` attribute as you can use the same name for multiple input fields. Just use the `[]` notation which will behave like an array of data. Use something like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="spec[]" placeholder="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="spec[]" placeholder="">
```

instead of:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="spec1" placeholder="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="spec2" placeholder="">
```

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your logic to aplly different id and name..

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addSpec', function(e) {

  //if a dynamic input does not exist
  let id = $("input[id^=spec_]").length + 1; 

   $("#customFields").append(`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec${id}" name="name${id}" data-id="${id}" placeholder="Spec Name" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">` +
       `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec_${id}" name="spec${id}" placeholder="" style="margin-bottom: 20px">`);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=customFields>

</div>

<button class="w-50 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="addSpec">Add Spec</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: Sorry Frenchy, but this is bad code for 2 reasons: `1` inspect the element the `id`s you generate are always the same. You string concatenation with the "id" is wrong. `2` getting the length without the `#customFields` could lead into a mean bug in the future

Comment: @caramba, yes its typo fixed with the interpolation  and no the lenght is correct, the id is lightly different spec and spec_, but its better to use with the id customfields

Comment: but it could be any `spec_*` on the entire page. and `3` there is no reason to use a number for the `name` attributes as stated in my answer